# If possible, how to include cut marks in PDF? (using watermark?)

Tags: pdf, multiple-files, cropmarks

**Update:**

OK, so I am thinking maybe the watermark package can do something about it. All we need is some sort of m by n dashed grid lines according to the `nup=` option in the `\includepdf` command. But I have no idea how to implement this in an automatic way.

**Original post:**

I can use `\includepdf` or just a normal PDF printer to "print" multiple PDFs on a single page, like this (in Adobe Acrobat):

[image]

Then the output is like this:
[image]

What I desire to have is to have a cut mark:
[image]

So I know where exactly to cut on a paper gutter.
It would be very helpful if I want to print the same page 6 times on a single A4, in the format of 2x3. So I can cut them accurately.

Even better if we can have a scissor like this:
[image]

Using the basic code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[
pages={33-38},
nup=1x2,     % or any format
landscape=false,
frame=false  % this is not a cut mark, which is something a want
]{Piano.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This can combine PDF pages as we wish. What I am looking for is not a "frame", but something similar, like gutter margins.

Any latex pages that does this, or serves similar purpose?

Comment: Can you provide the code for a page without the marks you want added? Since you can do that part, you don't need us to demonstrate that. Then somebody can show you how to add the additions you want. I'm not sure I understand the issue with getting the pages e.g. 3x1 or 1x3 or 2x2 or whatever. Don't you do that with an option to `\includepdf`?

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear. The end aim was to say if I want to print the same page 6 times on an A4, in the format of 2 by 3. I want to know accurately where to cut them on a paper gutter. I am wondering if it is possible to have these dashed lines automatically generated. Even better if I can have a little "scissor" next to the line.

Comment: You need ✂ `Unicode Character 'BLACK SCISSORS' (U+2702)` for the scissors and any drawing package to draw dashed lines. Perhaps [tag:pdfpages] and [tag:pgfpages] will help.

Answer (score 5):

You can draw arbitrary code on your pages, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,tikz}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[
duplicatepages=4,
nup=1x2,
landscape,
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}%
              \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
                \draw[red,dashed,line width=10pt](current page.east)--(current page.west);}
]{example-image-A5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume this would not automatically extend to any m by n pages? Say 2 by 3, or 1 by 4 ?

Comment: no, you will have to invest some work.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the crop package to produce bleed marks, and then render multiple pages on a single larger page (4 in 1 shown below).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[cam,cross]{crop}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\newcounter{pn}\setcounter{pn}{1}
\newcommand\page{\section{Page \thepn}\stepcounter{pn}\newpage}

\begin{document}

\page
\page
\page
\page

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which does not require loading Ti*k*Z and uses `pifont` for the scissors ding-bat.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,pifont}
\usepackage[calc]{picture}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf
[
pages={33-38},
  nup=1x2,
  landscape,
  frame=false,
  picturecommand={%
    \put(0,.5\paperheight){\line(1,0){\paperwidth}}%
    \put(15,.5\paperheight){\ding{33}}%
  }
]{kant}
\end{document}
```

[image: cut Kant to size]